# How to concatenate string in python

Tags: python-3.x, string

new = "file.txt"

source_path  = r"C:\Users\Shri Krishan\Documents"  + "\" +  new

print(source_path)

Error: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: To work with file and directory paths, I suggest using [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) or the more recent [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of using string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code:

```
new = "file.txt"

source_path = r"C:\Users\Shri Krishan\Documents" + "\\" + new

print(source_path)
```

result:

```
C:\Users\Shri Krishan\Documents\file.txt
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be nice. Also why concatenate two string literals? You could've simply written `r"C:\Users\Shri Krishan\Documents\" + new`.